# executing clickhouse on server is 20x faster than executing it from remote

Tags: database, clickhouse

I tested this query using clickhouse-benchmark

```
 select pageUrl ,
    pageTitle ,
    sum(visits) as visits ,
    count(DISTINCT visitorId) as visitors ,
    any(featuredImage) as featuredImage ,
     any(pageType) as pageType ,ssid
      FROM PageViews  FINAL  where  (createdAtDay >= toDate('2022-06-01') and createdAtDay <= toDate('2022-10-01'))  GROUP BY pageUrl,pageTitle,ssid  ORDER BY visits DESC
```

If executing the command from terminal on the server that's hosting clickhouse instance I get pretty fast response :

[image]

but when I try to execute same query remotely (which is the usual scenario, I'm not hosting my api in same server as clickhouse)
I get slow response :

[image]

I tried to get logs using this query :

```
SELECT
    event_time, query_duration_ms / 1000 AS secs,
    formatReadableSize(memory_usage) AS memory,
    Settings['max_threads'] AS threads,
    query
FROM system.query_log
WHERE (user = 'default') AND (type = 'QueryFinish') and (query like '%select pageUrl ...%')
ORDER BY event_time DESC
```

and it seems even in database logs the execution time is very big :

[image]

last 5 are the remote ones, first 5 are from the server, the time diff is very big.
is this normal? is there any type of config that I must setup ?

Comment: The obvious question is what is your network connection like to the remote server.

Comment: I tested from another server (dedicated server) and results are better. but I don't understand how network connection can affect queries that much? I'm only sending few bytes! and why it has high query_duration in database logs if it's the issue related to network ?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but the native protocol sends partial results, progress information and other response data during query processing, so a slow network could result in a lot of dead wait time on the TCP connection.  That's just a guess though.